# Date format and the hour is always 12:00:00.000

Tags: java, date

I got the problem with date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`, always when I parse some date the time is set to `12:00:00.000`.

This is my date formater:

```
DateFormat xmlDateFormatWithMs = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Comment: And what's the string you parse?

Comment: mmm it's seems that depends on HH format as Ludo6431 said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need 24-hours hour format. You need:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

With capital `HH` to specify you need a 24-hours format.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2016-09-27T18:33:39Z" )
```

## Details

Another solution is to avoid using the old SimoleDateFormat and java.util.Date classes as they are notoriously troublesome.

## Joda-Time

Pass your [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string directly to Joda-Time:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( myString );
```

## java.time

Or, preferably in java.time. The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode and advises migration to java.time.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That means up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-09-27T18:33:39Z" );
```

To adjust into other offsets or time zones, search Stack Overflow for `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` classes.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.